# How to change the colon to a comma after the vol.(num.) in bib-file or .tex file?

Tags: apa-style, bibliographystyle

[image]I need to use a comma instead of a colon between the volume and the page numbers in the references. How can I achieve this directly in the bib-file or alternatively directly in my .tex file?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,abstracton]{article}
\usepackage{apalike}
```

...

```
\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{referencefile.bib}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked,

> How can I achieve this directly in the bib-file or alternatively directly in my .tex file?

The answer is "neither in the bib file nor in the tex file". Since the formatting of bibliographic entries is governed by the bibliography style that's being employed, you need to edit the .bst ("bibliography style") file -- here, the file `apalike.bst`.

I therefore suggest you proceed as follows:

- Find the file `apalike.bst` in your TeX distribution. If you don't know how to do this, you may also download the file from the [CTAN](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/base). Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `apalike-comma.bst`.
- Open the file `apalike-comma.bst` in an editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- In this file, search for the BibTeX function `format.vol.num.pages`. (In my copy of the file, this function starts on line 392.)
- Within this function, locate the following line:

  ```
          { ":" * pages n.dashify * }
  ```

  Change this line to

  ```
          { ", " * pages n.dashify * }
  ```
- Save the file `apalike-comma.bst` either in the directory that contains your main tex file or a in directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to also update the filename database of your TeX distribution in a suitable manner. If you have no idea what the preceding sentence means, I suggest you choose the former option.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{apalike}
  ```

  to

  ```
  \bibliographystyle{apalike-comma}
  ```

  and perform a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Comment: Thanks, Mico. Your explanation is super detailed and helped me a lot. It works perfectly. Thank you so much!